# 502 Bad Gateway Error Displayed, Timeout Occurs

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am currently having some issues with my nginx and gunicorn setup. Once I have both of them enabled and go to the IP address established by digitalocean, it takes 5 minutes to show me 502 Bad Gateway Nginx. Afterwards I get a sentry error that reads:

"OperationalError
could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "myproject-postgres-staging-db-do-user-6482921-0.db.ondigitalocean.com" (64.225.42.160) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 25060?"

I have been trying all sorts of different things with my nginx and gunicorn configs as well as the settings.py file, but to no avail. I'm not sure if I did something wrong in relation to those methods hence why I didn't get any results, but I am out of ideas. Here's my code for reference.

Nginx config:

```
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name myproject.app www.myproject.app IP ADDRESS;    
    error_log /home/myuser/nginxError.log warn;
    access_log /home/myuser/nginx.log ;

    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    add_header Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin;
    add_header Feature-Policy: *;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy: default-src ;


    location /static {
        alias /My-Project/backend/staticfiles;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/My-Project/backend.sock;
        proxy_connect_timeout       300;
        proxy_send_timeout          300;
        proxy_read_timeout          300;
        send_timeout                300;
    }


    # listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    # ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myproject.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myproject.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    # include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    # ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.myproject.app) {
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = myproject.app) {
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = IP ADDRESS) {
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    server_name myproject.app www.myproject.app IP ADDRESS;
    listen 80;
    # return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/My-Project/backend
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --log-file /home/myuser/gunicorn.log --log-level error --timeout 600 --workers 10 --threads 9 --bind unix:/My-Project/backend.sock main.wsgi
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Error when attempting migration

```
root@mycontainer:/My-Project/backend# sudo python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "myproject-postgres-staging-db-do-user-6482921-0.db.ondigitalocean.com" (64.225.42.160) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 25060?
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 76, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "myproject-postgres-staging-db-do-user-6482921-0.db.ondigitalocean.com" (64.225.42.160) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 25060?
Sentry is attempting to send 0 pending error messages
Waiting up to 2 seconds
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

Database Config from settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': os.getenv("DB_ENGINE"),
                'NAME': os.getenv("DB_NAME"),
                'USER': os.getenv("DB_USER"),
                'PASSWORD': os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
                'HOST': os.getenv("DB_HOST"),
                'PORT': os.getenv("DB_PORT"),
                'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'require'},
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems that you have database access issue on django part. Please make sure you can access your database from django.

Comment: After putting in a couple commands, I've got the page to at least say the correct 504 error message. My settings.py file does include the new IP address, so it should be accepting it, but it still isn't. I also can't perform the migrate command with my manage.py file without getting the same message as the sentry error.

Comment: Please add these errors to your question so we can see what is the actual error.

Comment: Please add your database configuration from settings, looks like password could be possibly wrong, wrong port or just the db instance not accepting connections because of a security group

Comment: I just added the migration error and the database config. For the database config, I'm using the os.getenv method.

Comment: Turns out I just needed to go into the settings of my domain and add the IP address as a trusted source. Thank you both for you help though.